# What is unarmed weight?

Tags: fighter, weight

I'm doing research about fighter planes, and I've noticed two terms: unarmed weight and empty weight. I've tried to find what the difference between these two terms is, but I can't find a definition for unarmed weight. Is it just the weight of the fuel and no weapons (hence, unarmed), or is there a more specific definition connected to some other weight measurement, because there are several of those and I wouldn't know exactly what unarmed weight is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Empty is no fuel and no munitions.

Unarmed is with fuel and no munitions.

Where are you seeing these terms?

Comment: I'm seeing them on wikipedia pages and a couple other sites, specifically in reference to the Mig-25, with a difference of 29k kg for unarmed weight and 20k kg for empty weight. Wanted to confirm the difference between them.

Comment: It would be best, @Chickendragon, to put this info (including the links to wiki) in your question.